# Heroku - CSS not loading on a single page but everywhere else

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Sorry in advance, I know there are topics on this subject, but this is maddening!  I wouldn't be as frustrated if this problem wasn't limited to just the index. The CSS loads fine all on the pages of my app *except* the post/index page. I should note it runs perfectly locally and I've been banging my head against this since this morning so I may have overlooked something banal and apologize in advance.

Gem file

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

Production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Running the following was unsuccessful:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Specifying while assets to precompile in `production.rb` was unsuccessful

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( public.css public.js )   
config.assets.precompile += %w( assets/stylesheets )
```

Also tried changing the extensions from `.css` to `.scss` and adding a new `custom.scss`and linking to it without success.

Link to my app and the page in question:
https://clickbait22.herokuapp.com/

Link to its Github repository:
https://github.com/4thking/clickbait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running...

```
heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile
heroku open
```

In production, you must run rake assets:precompile to serve up anything in your app/assets folder. In development mode, Rails constantly checks for updates to the files and serves them each one separately.

It is nice when you're developing, but is quite slow in production. So, to speed things up, Rails has you run a single, longer task that shrinks and combines a bunch of files in app/assets, speeding up page loading times and reducing server load.

Hope this helps you out!

## **UPDATE:**

Whilst you said that you have tried doing the following, I want to include it for clarity regardless. Quite often it is important to precompile your assets before you push to Heroku. Inside the terminal this process would look similar to this...

```
rake assets:precompile
git commit -m 'Assets precompiled'
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the speedy reply!  I tried your suggestions and, unfortunately, it didn't resolve my issue. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: What a shame Ryan :( It was worth a try, I'll look at your Github repo now and see if I can spot anything.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've been moving style sheets around all day so I apologize in advance for the mess I've made.

Comment: Right, so I have cloned your project and despite what you have said about it running ok locally, I am afraid it doesn't for me. The problem seems to be inside the posts/index.html.erb file. Check again your div placements class names. I think it is not deployment issue but rather a styling one

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks so much for your help, that actually makes a lot of sense considering what's happening, I'll tinker around and see if I can replicate it locally.

Comment: Yes Ryan, I think this is the best thing you could do. Your code base is rather large and I think no better person knows how to fix it better than you. All the best

Comment: Hi Tim. I cloned it and you're absolutely right the slider is a mess.